# Jupiter applet default setting

Tags: jupiter

I would like to start Jupiter in `Power saving` mode but it always start in `Max performance` mode. I dopnt have a laptop.Im running it on an assembled desktop.
Any way to do it?

[image]

---

#### Edit

for jasmines
There are no such files as you mentioned
THe contents of the folder are

```
ashhab@ubuntu:~$ cd /var/jupiter/  
ashhab@ubuntu:/var/jupiter$ ls  
available_resolutions  resolution_saved  touchpad_saved  vga_saved
cpu_mode rotation_saved    UNKNOWN
ashhab@ubuntu:/var/jupiter$
```

Comment: What version of jupiter?

Comment: @jasmines 0.1.2

Comment: What if you create manually those files I suggested?

Comment: @jasmines k i'll try

Comment: @jasmines thamks that fixed it... edit your answer to add that point.

Comment: Just done! I forgot to ask: are you on 12.04?

Comment: @jasmines nope, on 10.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conf file are:

/var/jupiter/battery (for battery mode)

/var/jupiter/power (for AC mode)

Each file contains just one text entry that can be: powersave, high or super.

Create these files if they're missing.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/state

try to run /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/state and if it returns UNKNOWN then you have to look in state file there to changed it so it would recognize your battery

STEP BY STEP:

> ls /sys/class/power_supply/

now

> sudo gedit /usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/state

modify the line `AC_DEVICE=$(ls /sys/class/power_supply | grep "ADP\|AC")` replace `ADP\|AC` with the return of the command `ls /sys/class/power_supply/`

and now will work